# Concurrent VPN connection on Max OS X

Tags: macos, vpn

I need to to connect to a VPN for internet access. While I'm connected to that VPN I need to connect to another VPN for accessing local data on that network. When I'm try to connect, the first VPN disconnects and the internet access is gone. Is there any way to connect to more than one VPN at a time on Mac OS X?

Comment: You have to fix your configurations according to your needs, you probably only need to send/get data from certain IP/domain for both VPN, currently I believe that both are trying to send/get all data from your PC. What client do you use? Also did you get the configurations or create them yourself.

Comment: The first one is my University VPN that's required to access almost everything and the second one used for filtering bypassing. I make the first one manually but use the application for the second one.